# Newbie - Chrome Extension & Spotify API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, spotify

I've been out of the programming game for a while and trying to get back in for fun. I'm working on a dumb Chrome extension for the spotify web player that checks to see if the current playing song is tagged as explicit.

Spotify has two versions of their web player. The newer one makes it easy to see if a track is explicit but the older version doesn't always have this info. I did manage to extract the track ID and using the Spotify API, I theoretically should be able to pull the track info using something like: https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/4ckuS4Nj4FZ7i3Def3Br8W - replacing the ID with the currently playing track ID. Within the data in the URL is going to be

```
"explicit" : true,
```

or

```
"explicit" : false,
```

I just can't figure out how to get the extension to grab and parse this data. I've been trying to use XMLHttpRequest functions but nothing is working and I'm seeing some info with cross-domain issues and I'm wondering if that's what I'm running into since the extension is on the local machine and not *.spotify.com. But again, being new to chrome/js I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you are retrieving from the api is in the json format, and thus all you need to do is parse the string you received from the http request using `JSON.parse()` [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).  All you need to do is parse that data, which will turn it into a javascript object.  from there all you need to do is grab that boolean with `parsedObject.explicit`.  If you don't know what json or objects are here are two simple explanations for each (respectively) [understanding json](https://spring.io/understanding/JSON) and [understanding objects](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_definition.asp).

If your http request is failing, it's most likely due to you not setting up your extension's website accessing [permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions) in the manifest correctly.  Make sure a permission for accessing api.spotify.com is in place and the [Match pattern](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns) is set up to correctly to whitelist the page you are trying to access with your http request.  (`"https://api.spotify.com/*"` in your case)